# Falied to load resource glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, http-status-code-404, glyphicons

I am working with bootstrap in my website the icons are not displaying, In web console it is showing as

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://mywebsite.in/lgm/assets/lib/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

And the directory structure of the bootstrap is

- assets

  - lib

    - bootstrap

      - css
      - fonts
      - js

Anyone help me regarding this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: check bootstrap.css files with this font glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2, where it is point or please provide what is written there

Comment: `@font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';src:url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot);src:url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regulard41d.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2) format('woff2'),url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff) format('woff'),url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf) format('truetype'),url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular) format('svg')}` in bootstarp.min.css I have this code regarding glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2

Comment: can you upload code some so i can check it

Comment: Thanks for response **Paresh Gami** one of colleague solved the issue.

Comment: @Jallipalli Phanindra Can you please tell me how did you solved this issue? 
I have fonts in the folder, path is correct but still getting error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove error about glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300578/how-to-remove-error-about-glyphicons-halflings-regular-woff2-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind the error is because `glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2` cannot be found on the path that is being looked for. This can be rectified by putting the file on folder. A fresh download of Bootstrap contains the file in the Fonts folder.

Answer (score -1):

There are few solutions:

- you can hard-remove these lines from your bootstrap.css file (if you do not using them)
- you can upload missing fonts to specified path (`/lgm/assets/lib/bootstrap/fonts/` in this case)
- you can [generate your customized bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) js/css without glyphicons