# Summernote in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, font-awesome, summernote

I tried implementing summernote wysiwyg editor in my Asp.Net MVC project as per the tutorial [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/bootstrap-wysiwyg-editor-in-Asp-Net-mvc).

I thought I was getting the same issue as [this guy](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/1288) and implemented the suggestions but still no avail.

I've also ammended my web.config file as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300578/how-to-remove-error-about-glyphicons-halflings-regular-woff2-not-found) to try to fix the glyphicons problem but also to no avail.

If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong it'd be greatly appreciated.

See the text area in the text area and the button icons not rendering

[image: rendered]

Rendered HTML according to Chrome Debugger

[image: html]

.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Recipe.Instructions, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Recipe.Instructions, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Recipe.Instructions, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

bundle

```
 public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/font-awesome.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css",
                      "~/Content/globalStyles.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/summernote").Include(
                "~/Content/summernote/summernote.css"
                ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/summernote").Include(
               "~/Content/summernote/summernote.js"
               ));
        }
    }
```

file structure

[image: sln]

chrome errors

[image: errors]

Comment: I don't know anything about summernote, but `@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Recipe.Instructions, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })` looks very wrong.  Perhaps you meant `@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Recipe.Instructions, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})`?

Comment: And don't post code as images, it helps absolutely no one doing a search (and forced me to type all of that by hand)

Comment: @PaulAbbot `new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })` was generated by vs2015. I tried the older way and it made no difference. Changing my question now to replace screenshots with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ammended my scripts section in my `cshtml` file to include the css bundle like so

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render(
        "~/bundles/jqueryval",
        "~/bundles/summernote",
        "~/Scripts/recipeCreate.js",
        "~/Scripts/wysiwyg.js");
    @Styles.Render(
        "~/Content/summernote"
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed bundle.config

`bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/summernote/summernote.css").Include(
                      "~/Content/summernote/summernote.css"
   ));`

And changed using this bundle in `_Layout.cshtml`

```
`@Styles.Render("~/Content/summernote/summernote.css")`
```