# How to solve glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 Err_Aborted issue in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootswatch

So I have a project where I want to change the theme of BootStrap. So, I took theme from [BootSwatch](https://bootswatch.com/) and the theme is selected is [Lumen](https://bootswatch.com/lumen/bootstrap.css). Now in my Bundle.Config file, I made below changes.

```
  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      //"~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/bootstrap-lumen.css",
                      "~/Content/superslides.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
```

Now as soon as I start using the Lumen Theme, I get error (in dev tool) as below:
[image]

P.S: This **does not** happen when I use **normal BootStrap** theme. I looked into [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300578/how-to-remove-error-about-glyphicons-halflings-regular-woff2-not-found). But it talks about making IIS changes and all. But my problem **only occurs** when I use **LUMEN** theme. How to get rid of this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I have downloaded the missing files from [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/dist/fonts) and added those in `fonts` folder of my project.

Then added these lines within `<system.webServer>` section in `web.config` file of my project:

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
</staticContent>
```

In your case, download [glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2) file.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: smooth! we were getting this error almost for an year, nobody did anything, today I finally wanted to fix it and you fixed for me

Comment: The current standard mime types are `application/font-woff` and `font/woff2`, see https://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/#appendix-b and https://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF2/#IMT

Comment: This breaks my solution completely.

Answer (score 15):

As an alternate to **Reyan Chougle's** answer, this can also be fixed through IIS:

1. Open IIS, click on your site.

[image: Step 1]

2. In the middle section, under the grouping ***IIS***, double-click ***MIME Types***

[image: Step 2]

3. Edit or add ***woff*** and/or ***woff2*** extensions:

   - .woff -> application/x-font-woff
   - .woff2 -> application/font-woff2

[image: Step 4]

*NOTE: Tested on IIS 8.5 in the Chrome web browser*

Comment: I'm confused as to why I'm being down voted. Can anyone that is going to at least explain why?

Comment: It shouldn't be downvoted. It is a potential fix too.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue.

In first attempt, I have added the MIME type (font-woff2) directly at the IIS server, it worked. However after deployment(CI/CD) MIME type automatically got removed.

In Second attempt, I have added staticContent tags in web.config and it worked like a permanent fix.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the missing file via CDN:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with **WordPress**. I had a folder on the root of the directory with a path to the font, and for some reason, I got **net::ERR_ABORTED** and **404 (Not Found)**. So what I did was to move those fonts to `wp-content/plugins` where other fonts were defined such as FontAwesome... and it works!